# UI is messed up in some applications on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, menu

[image: Messed up UI in some applications]

I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit & some(but nowhere near all) applications have messed-up UI as seen in the screenshot. The menu bar items don't have any space between them & dropdowns & right-click menus are just black rectangles. In addition, buttons are off(too big, funny looking). Other applications, such as the terminal & FireFox work just fine.

What is the source of this problem & how do I fix it?

Comment: Start button > Preferences > Customize Look and Feel > Color - do you have the option ticked to use a customized color scheme?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that's what the problem was?

Comment: I would change your theme to one you like. Have you downloaded various themes and installed them?  Are they LXDE compatible? as this can occur if you use themes built for other desktops (and is fixed by changing theme back to a more LXDE compatible theme). Spme settings can also be changed via *openbox configuration*

Comment: I'm using the Lubuntu default theme & it's only messed up in some applications including VirtualBox & VLC, but not all of them.