# Some applications are drawn with wrong interface

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, desktop-environments, interface, session

This is on Lubuntu 18.04 with
Desktop: LXDE
Session: Lubuntu
Window Manager: Openbox
*(I'm not exactly sure what this information means.)*

I must have uninstalled or changed something vital today, because some applications now have humongous buttons and an altered menu appearance. [This user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258977/ui-is-messed-up-in-some-applications-on-lubuntu-18-04) appears to have the exact same issue, and it is not caused by custom Colors in Customize Look and Feel, as was suggested in the comments.

Non-exhaustive list of applications that show the issue:

- qterminal
- lximage-qt
- [lximage-qt --screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnRHO.png)
- vlc
- [keepassxc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9znfM.png)
- qps
- edit: ... they seem to all be Qt apps

For reference, here is approximately what things ought to look:

- [Look and Feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stIOy.png)

---

Steps I've taken that might have caused this?

- I installed and uninstalled lxqt
- I uninstalled gnome-desktop
- I uninstalled some (unknown which) ppas I thought I no longer used

Steps I've taken trying to solve the issue:

- back-tracked on both lxqt and gnome-desktop with the help of logs
- `sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop`
- renamed ~/.config
- installed `qt4-qtconfig` and checked in `qtconfig` the UI style is set to "GTK+"
- `apt install lxde`: Changing desktop environment to "LXDE" instead of "Lubuntu" on the login screen seems to provide an identical interface, and does solve the display issue. I am sadly not knowledgable enough to understand what is at play here, so I am hoping someone else can look at the above list of apps to find a common factor.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: You mention `qterminal` which is a LXQt application & not `lxterminal` used by LXDE. LUbuntu 18.04 LTS didn't use LXQt or GNOME so your removal of non-installed packages then re-install changed your system significantly. You mention qt4-config; but Qt5 only becomes involved with Lubuntu 18.10 & later not 18.04 or earlier & wasn't ever used by Lubuntu before 18.10 (except in Lubuntu Next releases which only had 9 months of support; a 18.04 LXQt system needed upgrade to 18.10 as LXQt wasn't LTS for 18.04). Your details imply you may have made a mess and I'd suggest install a *supported* release.

Comment: I'm on really old hardware, so I wanted to avoid upgrading. Also, never change a running system etc.. I'll file this as an experience and reinstalled the whole system from scratch.

Comment: I'm using a 2008 dell right now (core2 era) and I've QA tested all releases on it, including much older boxes (2003 *i386* boxes were used up to 19.04, and 2005 & newer for all releases), but I don't know what you consider "*old*". Don't forget 18.04 is in it's last months of support (EOSS is only till April 2023) with *i386* not included in ESM/UA, though only a subset of packages are included anyway.

Comment: Also be aware Lubuntu 18.04 LTS has no upgrade path as the later release notes told you (read https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/ & "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system.*"  but this won't impact you if you're only intended to use your system a few more months (ie. till April 2023).